# How to get max value in below case (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have the following table:

```
ID      Code
1       A001
2       A001
3       A001
4       A002
5       A001
6       A002
```

I want to get the max value of `ID` where `Code` is `A001`. It should be `3`.

Here is another example:

```
ID      Code
1       A001
2       A002
3       A001
4       A002
5       A001
6       A002
```

In this case, `ID` should be `1`.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS product and version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the "last" row of the initial sequence.  Based on your question:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id < (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.code <> 'A001'  -- not NOT EQUALS
             ) 
order by t1.id desc;
```

It seems more reasonable that `'A001'` would not be hard-coded but calculated as the "first" value.

If that is the case:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      order by t.id
     ) top1
where t.id < (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.code <> top1.id  -- not NOT EQUALS
             ) 
order by t1.id desc;
```

This needs to be tweaked if all codes are the same.  But in your sample data you have multiple values.

With window functions, you can express this as:

```
select top (1) t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when code <> first_code then id end) over () as first_notcode_id
      from (select t.*,
                   first_value(code) over (order by id) as first_code
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where first_notcode_id is null or
      id < first_notcode_id
order by id;
```

Comment: I have an other example  ID      Code
1       A002
2       A002
3       A001
4       A002
5       A001
6       A002 result should be 3. how to i resolve it

Comment: @ZICOTRAN . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, please ask as a *new* question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports window function, Here is 1 way to achieve the desired result

```
SELECT MAX(ID), CODE
FROM (SELECT D.ID, D.CODE, D.ID - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY D.CODE ORDER BY D.ID) RN
      FROM DATA_TABLE D
      WHERE CODE = 'A001') X
WHERE RN = 0
GROUP BY CODE
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c7883a0bd1c95c29edf90f1a689828ae) is the fiddle.

Comment: In this case https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e08fc1328ba3b8b5580b4fcd69c6dba8 I think that it's incorrect